# Git and Vim - Formatted wrong with git diff, but correct with git commit --amend

Tags: windows, git, ubuntu, vim, zsh

I am using Ubuntu for Windows.

Vim and git work fine when calling git `commit --amend`, but calling `git diff` or `git log` results in improperly formatted output. Can anyone please explain when the output is not formatted correctly like when calling `git commit --amend`?

I'm using `zsh` with git aliases, which is why it says I called `gc!` and not `git commit --amend`, etc.

[image: git commit --amend]

[image: git diff]

Comment: Do you use windows or linux?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu on Windows: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6#activetab=pivot:overviewtab

With `Cmder` and `zsh`

Comment: Does it work without WSL (git bash)?

Answer (score 0):

The stuff you're seeing—the `[32m`, `[m`, and so on—is the result of partly, but not completely, stripping out colorization codes.  Git is printing <kbd>ESC</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd> (optional digits) <kbd>m</kbd> so as to tell your terminal emulator / display window to change colors, backgrounds, and so on. The pager you're using is for some reason removing the <kbd>ESC</kbd> but leaving the rest in.

To find out which pager you're using, use:

```
git var GIT_PAGER
```

To correct its behavior ... well, that depends on which pager you're using. :-)